# Testing branded SharePoint 2010 solutions

Tags: branding, testing

We are implementing an extensively branded SP2010 site.  As part of this effort, we need to be able to confirm that our branding does not break any out of the box (OOTB) SharePoint functionality.

Are there any good resources or existing test cases that we can start with for creating our test plan?  Ideally, we'd be able to run these test cases against an OOTB site and the branded site with little or no modification to the test case.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about a posted test case.  I would take this approach:

1. Which Site Templates will you allow to be used
2. Which features will be made available to those sites (outside of their required features)
3. Decide which webparts you will test against
4. Build a matrix off those decisions.  If you want to cover
   every scenario you need to list every site template and feature
   available.
5. I would then create my test area and include a site of
   the specific templates identified with the appropriate features
   activated.
6. In each of these sites you will need to create some pages and add
   out of the box web parts to the pages.

You should be able to add/remove your branding to these sites to see the affects on the layouts and SharePoint functions, and track them against your matrix.

To get list of web templates you can use PowerShell

```
get-spwebtemplate
```

The following will return list of all available features

```
Get-SPFeature
```

The following will list web parts available in the site collection gallery (courtesy of Ram Gopinathan MCM).

```
param ($url = $(Read-Host -Prompt "Enter URL for site"))  
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea SilentlyContinue 

$GalleryItem = @"  
    using System; 

    namespace WebPartGallery{ 
        public class GalleryItem{ 
            public string Name { get; set; } 
            public string Title { get; set; } 
            public string Description { get; set; } 
            public string Url {get; set;} 
            public string Group { get; set; } 
        } 
    } 
"@ 

Add-Type $GalleryItem -Language CSharpVersion3 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$al = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 

function Get-WebPartGalleryItems() 
{ 
    $site = Get-SPSite $url 
    $wpCatalog = $site.GetCatalog([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::WebPartCatalog) 

    foreach($item in $wpCatalog.Items) 
    { 
        $galleryItem = New-Object -TypeName "WebPartGallery.GalleryItem" 
        $galleryItem.Name = $item.Name 
        $galleryItem.Title = $item.Title  
        $galleryItem.Description = $item["Description"] 
        $galleryItem.Url = $item.Url  
        $galleryItem.Group = $item["Group"]  
        $index = $al.Add($galleryItem) 
    } 
    return $al  
} 

Get-WebPartGalleryItems | sort-object -property Group | ft *
```